# Specifying RowDefinition.Height in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

When you're creating a Grid in xaml you can define the RowDefinitions as such

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

I have a need to do the same thing in code. I know I can write

```
RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
row.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
```

but that doesn't help me much since I've got a string coming in. I could probably create my own "string to GridLength" converter but this doesn't feel right since it works ever so smooth from xaml. Of course, I've tried the following but it doesn't work

```
row.Height = new GridLength("*");
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `GridLength` struct has a `TypeConverter` defined which is being used when instantiated from Xaml. You can use it in code as well. It's called `GridLengthConverter`

If you look at `GridLength.cs` with Reflector it looks like this. Notice the `TypeConverter`

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), TypeConverter(typeof(GridLengthConverter))]
public struct GridLength : IEquatable<GridLength>
{
    //...
}
```

You can use it like

```
GridLengthConverter gridLengthConverter = new GridLengthConverter();
row.Height = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");
```

Answer (score 14):

you are missing to include your RowDefinition to RowDefinitions

```
RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
row.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
YourGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
```

See you!
Rutx

Answer (score 11):

No need to create a converter, there already is one, which is being used by the XAML-parser as well:

```
var converter = new GridLengthConverter();
row.Height = (GridLength)converter.ConvertFromString("*");
```

On a sidenote, you will find converters like this for **a lot** of types, as many get parsed from strings in XAML, e.g. `BrushConverter` & `ImageSourceConverter`

Comment: Thanks, never heard of Type Converters before. Had to pick an answer and your didnt compile since GridLength is not nullable so.. Thanks for the tip of the other converters as well

Answer (score 0):

Following Rutx answer I would make it even shorter

```
grdLbx.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star) });
```